# double commande in package.json don't work

Tags: npm, handlebars.js, package.json

I have an app where I would like to compile all my handlebars template/partials

The command I execute is (npx cause is a local package) =>

Build Views

```
npx handlebars ./public/templates/views -f ./public/templates/view.js --extension 'hbs'
```

Build Template

```
npx handlebars ./public/templates/partials -f ./public/templates/partials.js --extension 'hbs'
```

It work if I run them independently
now, I tried to combine them,

```
  "scripts": {
    "hbs": "npx handlebars ./public/templates/views -f ./public/templates/view.js --extension 'hbs' && npx handlebars ./public/templates/partials -f ./public/templates/partials.js --extension 'hbs'",
  },
```

but the command do not run, instead, I get prompted with the library !help like if the command is invalid.

Is there something I miss ?

Comment: What is the error message? And not sure it is the problem, but you do not need the npx in the script command as local commands are in scope for scripts.

Comment: it's not an error, the command just don't run. and give me the help page.

The command should create a file, nothing happens

Comment: I get the help page when the target directory does not exist, or does not contain files with the specified extension. Couple of ideas:
1) Try removing the single quotes from around the extension, in case they are being included when parsed from the script
2) Try absolute path to public/templates in case somehow running from different working directory

Comment: remove the single quote did work, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments on question, the single quotes are being incorrectly included into the `--extension` option for handlebars. The suggested format for the script is:

```
"scripts": {
    "hbs": "handlebars ./public/templates/views -f ./public/templates/view.js --extension hbs && handlebars ./public/templates/partials -f ./public/templates/partials.js --extension hbs",
  },
```